# how to get form values from referrer in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net webforms is there a way to get the posted values of the previous page without having to send through query strings?

I want to pickup TxtSearch on the next page and I though I remember someway of doing without session or querystring (i thought you could you something like     Request.Form();)

```
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" onclick="BtnSearch_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton></td>
        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="BtnShowAll" runat="server" onclick="BtnShowAll_Click">Show All Shelters</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" Runat=server Text="submit" PostBackUrl="~/NewPage.aspx" />
```

Then, in the NewPage.aspx.cs, you can access the TextBox control on Default.aspx as follows:-

```
public void page_load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
TextBox tb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("Text1");
Response.Write(tb.Text);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are posted you should be able to use Request and then your variable inside square brackets and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from MSDN: [How to Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).

An ASP.NET page posts to itself by default but you can post to a different page. See [How to Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx) and [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtSearch = Request["TxtSearch"];
```